# How can I generalize my sampling framework?

Tags: haskell, sampling, generalization

In the context of a stochastic ray tracer, I'd like to decouple the MC integration (path tracing, bidirectional path tracing) from sample generation (uniform random, stratified, poisson, metropolis, ...). Most of this is already implemented, but it's tedious to use. So I ditched that and try build something nicer, by splitting sampled computations in two phases: In `SampleGen` you are allowed to request a random value using the `mk1d` and `mk2d` functions, which are then supplied with actual `Float`s by the sampling algorithm. Those values can be examined in `SampleRun` to do the actual computation. Here's some code with the interesting bits of a stratified sampler and it's use:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import Control.Monad.Primitive
import System.Random.MWC as MWC

-- allows to construct sampled computations
newtype SampleGen s m a = SampleGen (StateT s m a)
                       deriving ( Functor, Applicative, Monad
                                , MonadState s, MonadTrans )

-- allows to evaluate sampled computations constructed in SampleGen
newtype SampleRun s m a = SampleRun (StateT s m a)
                       deriving ( Functor, Applicative, Monad
                                , MonadState s )

-- a sampled computation, parametrized over the generator's state g,
-- the evaluator's state r,  the underlying monad m and the result
-- type a
type Sampled g r m a = SampleGen g m (SampleRun r m a)

----------------------
-- Stratified Sampling
----------------------

-- | we just count the number of requested 1D samples
type StratGen = Int

-- | the pre-computed values and a RNG for additional ones
type StratRun m = ([Float], Gen (PrimState m))

-- | specialization of Sampled for stratified sampling
type Stratified m a = Sampled StratGen (StratRun m) m a

-- | gives a sampled value in [0..1), this is kind
--   of the "prime" value, upon which all computations
--   are built
mk1d :: PrimMonad m => Stratified m Float
mk1d = do
  n1d <- get
  put $ n1d + 1

  return $ SampleRun $ do
    fs <- gets fst
    if length fs > n1d
      then return (fs !! n1d)
      else gets snd >>= lift . MWC.uniform

-- | gives a pair of stratified values, should really also
--   be a "prime" value, but here we just construct them
--   from two 1D samples for fun
mk2d :: (Functor m, PrimMonad m) => Stratified m (Float, Float)
mk2d = mk1d >>= \f1 -> mk1d >>= \f2 ->
  return $ (,) <$> f1 <*> f2

-- | evaluates a stratified computation
runStratified
  :: (PrimMonad m)
  => Int            -- ^ number of samples
  -> Stratified m a -- ^ computation to evaluate
  -> m [a]          -- ^ the values produced, a list of nsamples values
runStratified nsamples (SampleGen c) = do
  (SampleRun x, n1d) <- runStateT c 0
  -- let's just pretend I'd use n1d to actually
  -- compute stratified samples
  gen <- MWC.create
  replicateM nsamples $ evalStateT x ([{- samples would go here #-}], gen)

-- estimate Pi by Monte Carlo sampling
-- mcPi :: (Functor m, PrimMonad m) => Sampled g r m Float
mcPi :: (Functor m, PrimMonad m) => Stratified m Float
mcPi = do
  v <- mk2d
  return $ v >>= \(x, y) -> return $ if x * x + y * y < 1 then 4 else 0

main :: IO ()
main = do
  vs <- runStratified 10000 mcPi :: IO [Float]
  print $ sum vs / fromIntegral (length vs)
```

The missing part here is that in it's current form, the `mcPi` function has the type

```
mcPi :: (Functor m, PrimMonad m) => Stratified m Float
```

while it should really be something like

```
mcPi :: (Functor m, PrimMonad m) => Sampled g r m Float
```

Admitted, the four type parameters on `Sampled` aren't exactly beautiful, but at least something like this would be useful. In summary, I'm looking for something allowing to express computations like `mcPi` independent of the sampling algorithm, e.g.:

- a uniform random sampler does not need to maintain any state in the `SampleGen` phase, and needs only a RNG in the `SampleRun` phase
- both, the stratified and the poisson disk sampler (and probably others) keep track of the number of 1D and 2D samples needed and precompute them into a vector, and they would be allowed to share a `SampleGen` and `SampleRun` implementation, to differ only in what happens inbetween `SampleGen` and `SampleRun` (how the vector is actually filled)
- a metropolis sampler would use a [lazy sample generation](http://www.iit.bme.hu/~szirmay/paper50_electronic.pdf) technique in it's `SampleRun` phase

I'd like to compile it using GHC, so extensions like `MultiParamTypeClasses` and `TypeFamilies` are ok to me, but I did not come up with anything remotely usable.

PS: As motivation, some [pretty pictures](https://plus.google.com/photos/107968783614195434185/albums/5660724573840020945). And the code in it's current form is on [GitHub](https://github.com/waldheinz/bling)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to start off with a radically different question, "What should the code look like"?, and then work towards the question "How is the sampling framework put together"?.

#### What the code should look like

The definition of `mcPi` should be

```
mcPi :: (Num s, Num p) => s -> s -> p
mcPi x y = if x * x + y * y < 1 then 4 else 0
```

The Monte Carlo estimation of pi is that, given two numbers (that happen to come from the interval [0..1)) pi is the area of a square if they fall within a circle, otherwise it's 0. The Monte Carlo estimation of pi doesn't know anything about computation. It doesn't know if it's going to be repeated, or anything about where the numbers came from. It does know that the numbers should be uniformly distributed over the square, but that's a topic for a different question. The Monte Carlo estimation of pi is just a function from the samples to the estimate.

Other random things will know that they are part of a random process. A simple random process might be: flip a coin, if the coin comes up "heads", flip it again.

```
simpleRandomProcess :: (Monad m, MonadCoinFlip m) => m Coin
simpleRandomProcess =
    do
        firstFlip <- flipACoin
        case firstFlip of 
            Heads -> flipACoin
            Tails -> firstFlip
```

This random process would like to be able to see things like

```
data Coin = Heads | Tails

class MonadCoinFlip m where
    flipACoin :: m Coin -- The coin should be fair
```

Random processes may change how much random data they need based on the results of previous experiments. This suggests that we will ultimately need to provide a `Monad`.

#### The interface

You would like to "decouple the MC integration (path tracing, bidirectional path tracing) from sample generation (uniform random, stratified, poisson, metropolis, ...)". In your examples, they all want to sample floats. That suggests the following class

```
class MonadSample m where
    sample :: m Float -- Should be on the interval [0..1)
```

This is very similar to the [existing MonadRandom class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.13/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html), except for two things. A `MonadRandom` implementation essentially needs to provide a uniformly random `Int` in some range of its own choosing. Your sampler will provide a `Float` sample of unknown distribution on the interval [0..1). This is different enough to justify having your own new class.

Due to the upcoming `Monad` `Applicative` change, I'm instead going to suggest a different name for this class, `SampleSource`.

```
class SampleSource f where
    sample :: f Float -- Should be on the interval [0..1)
```

`sample` replaces `mk1d` in your code. `mk2d` can also be replaced, again not knowing what the source of the samples will be. `sample2d`, the replacement for `mk2d`, will work with any `Applicative` sample source, it doesn't need it to be a `Monad`. The reason it doesn't need a `Monad` is it won't decide how many samples to get, or what else to do, based on the result of samples; the structure of its computation is known ahead of time.

```
sample2d :: (Applicative f, SampleSource f) => f (Float, Float)
sample2d = (,) <$> sample <*> sample
```

If you are going to allow the sample source to introduce interactions between dimensions, for example for Poisson disk sampling, you'd need to add that to the interface, either explicitly enumerating the dimensions

```
class SampleSource f where
    sample   :: f Float
    sample2d :: f (Float, Float)
    sample3d :: f (Float, Float, Float)
    sample4d :: f (Float, Float, Float, Float)
```

or using some vector library.

```
class SampleSource f where
    sample  :: f Float
    samples :: Int -> f (Vector Float)
```

#### Implementing the interface

Now, we need to describe how each of your sample sources can be used as a `SampleSource`. As an example, I'll implement `SampleSource` for one of the worst sample sources there is.

```
newtype ZeroSampleSourceT m a = ZeroSampleSourceT {
    unZeroSampleSourceT :: IdentityT m a
} deriving (MonadTrans, Monad, Functor, MonadPlus, Applicative, Alternative, MonadIO)

instance (Monad m) => SampleSource (ZeroSampleSourceT m a) where
    sample = return 0

runZeroSampleSourceT :: (Monad m) => ZeroSampleSourceT m a -> m a
runZeroSampleSourceT = runIdentityT . unZeroSampleSourceT
```

When all `Monad`s are `Applicative` I'd instead write

```
instance (Applicative f) => SampleSource (ZeroSampleSourceT f) where
    sample = pure 0
```

I'll also implement an MWC uniform `SampleSource`.

```
newtype MWCUniformSampleSourceT m a = MWCUniformSampleSourceT m a {
    unMWCUniformSampleSourceT :: ReaderT (Gen (PrimState m)) m a
} deriving (MonadTrans, Monad, Functor, MonadPlus, Applicative, Alternative, MonadIO)

runMWCUniformSampleSourceT :: MWCUniformSampleSourceT m a -> (Gen (PrimState m)) -> m a
runMWCUniformSampleSourceT = runReaderT . unMWCUniformSampleSourceT

-- MWC's uniform generates floats on the open-closed interval (0,1]
uniformClosedOpen :: PrimMonad m => Gen (PrimState m) -> m Float
uniformClosedOpen = fmap (\x -> x - 2**(-33)) . uniform

instance (PrimMonad m) => SampleSource (MWCUniformSampleSourceT m) where
    sample = MWCUniformSampleSourceT . ReaderT $ uniformClosedOpen
```

We won't completely implement `Stratified` or `runStratified`, since your example code doesn't contain complete implementations for them.

#### But I want to know how many samples will be used ahead of time

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do with "stratified" sampling. Pre-generating numbers, and using a generator when those run out isn't what I understand stratified sampling to be. If you are going to provide a monadic interface to something, you won't be able to tell ahead of time what will be executed, so you won't be able to predict how many samples a computation will need before you start executing it. If you can settle for only an `Applicative` interface, then you can test ahead of time how many samples will be needed by the entire computation.

#### But Poisson Disk sampling needs to know how many points are being sampled ahead of time

If a single sampling can depend on both the number of samples needed and the number of dimensions, like in Poisson Disk sampling, those need to be passed to the sampler when they become known.

```
class SampleSource f where
    sample   :: f Float
    samples  :: Int -> f ([Float])
    sampleN  :: Int -> f (Vector Float)
    samplesN :: Int -> Int -> f ([Vector Float])
```

You could generalize this to sampling in arbitrary shapes in arbitrary dimensions, which is what we'd need to do if we took the next leap.

#### Applicative query language with a Monadic interpreter

We can go, very, very elaborate and make an `Applicative` query language for requests for samples. The language will need to add two features on top of what `Applicative` already does. It will need to be able to repeat requests and it will need to group requests for samples together to identify which groupings are meaningful. It's motivated by the following code, which wants to get 6 different 2d samples, where `sample2d` is the same as our first definition.

```
take 6 (repeat sample2d)
```

First, we'll need to be able to repeat things over and over. The nicest way to this would be if we could write, e.g.

```
take 6 (repeat sample) :: SampleSource f => [f Float]
```

We'd need a way to go from an `[f a]` to `f [a]`. This already exists; it's `Data.Traversable`'s `sequenceA`, which requires that `f` be `Applicative`. So we already get repetition from `Applicative`.

```
sequenceA . take 6 . repeat $ sample2d
```

To group requests together, we'll add a function to `mark` which groupings are meaningful.

```
sequenceA . take 6 . repeat . mark $ sample2d
```

and a class for things that can mark some grouping. If we need more meaning than just groupings - for example if the internal things should be dependent or independent, we'd add it here.

```
class Mark f where
    mark :: f a -> f a
```

If everything is going to be very homogeneous, we might add a class for query-able sample sources

```
class (Applicative f, Mark f, SampleSource f) => QueryableSampleSouce f where
```

Now we will talk about the idea of a monad that has a more-optimized query language. Here we will start using all of those GHC-specific extensions; specifically `TypeFamilies`.

```
class MonadQuery m where
    type Query m :: * -> *
    interpret :: (Query m a) -> m a
```

And finally a class for monad sample sources with an `Applicative` query language

```
class (MonadQuery m, QueryableSampleSource (Query m), SampleSource m, Monad m) => MonadSample m where
```

At this point, we will want to work out what laws these should follow. I'd suggest a few:

```
interpret sample == sample
interpret (sequenceA a) = sequence (interpret a)
```

That is, without a `mark`, sample sources don't get to do anything terribly special with the queries. This would mean that a query that wants to be subject to Poisson disk's special treatment of 2d points and special treatment of the set of points would need to be marked twice:

```
 mark . sequenceA . take 6 . repeat . mark $ sample2d
```

The `Applicative` query language sort-of corresponds with your `StratGen` type; by having a mearly `Applicative` interface it allows you to look ahead at the structure of the incoming query. The `Monad` then corresponds with your `StratRun` type.